# Regex - Validation of numeric with up to 10 decimal places (0.01 - 100.0000000000)

Tags: regex, decimal

I am just curious if this regex expression will be able to be shorten. it should allow ten digits.

```
/^(?!0+(?:\.0+)?$)(\d{1,2}\.\d{1,10}|\d{1,2}|(100)|(100\\.00)|(100\\.0000000000)|(100\\.000000000)|(100\\.00000000)|(100\\.0000000)|(100\\.000000)|(100\\.00000)|(100\\.0000)|(100\\.0000)|(100\\.000)|(100\\.0))$/
```

Comment: Which language (and therefore which regex engine) are you using and what question are you attempting to answer?

Comment: And what is it supposed to accomplish? Are you aware that `.` is a meta-character?

Comment: My bad, it should be the one below, I didn't realize that \ is missing
/^(?!0+(?:\.0+)?$)(\d{1,2}\.\d{1,10}|\d{1,2}|(100)|(100\.00)|(100\.0000000000)|(100\.000000000)|(100\.00000000)|(100\.0000000)|(100\.000000)|(100\.00000)|(100\.0000)|(100\.0000)|(100\.000)|(100\.0))$/

Comment: this is in angular (frontend), I am sorry I am not familiar with these.

Comment: validation pattern for decimal (0.01 - 100.0000000000) use in form validation.

Comment: I want to work on regex expression 0.01-100.00 with ten decimal places. Whats a numerical comparison?

Comment: It should be either `/^(?![0.]+$)(?:\d{1,2}(?:\.\d{1,10})?|100(?:\.0{1,10})?)$/` ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/C67viW/2)) or - if you mean live input validation - `/^(?:\d{1,2}(?:\.\d{0,10})?|100(?:\.0{0,10})?)$/` (where you must allow `0` at the start, or you will not be able to input `0.01`) ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/C67viW/1)).

Comment: 1. A numerical comparison is where you compare numbers, with the `<`, `<=`, `==`, `!=`, `>=` and `>` operators. 2. Why you want to allow them to enter 10 zeros as decimal places? They don't add anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use

```
/^(?![0.]+$)(?:\d{1,2}(?:\.\d{1,10})?|100(?:\.0{1,10})?)$/
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/C67viW/2).

*Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `(?![0.]+$)` - no only `0` and/or `.` chars till end of string are allowed
- `(?:` - either of

  - `\d{1,2}(?:\.\d{1,10})?` - one or two digits and then an optional occurrence of a `.` and one to ten digits
- `|` - or

  - `100(?:\.0{1,10})?` - `100` and then an optional occurrence of a `.` and one to ten `0` chars
- `)` - end of the group
- `$` - end of string.